# Why following code doesn't run an exception for negative inputs?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to write a simple code when user enters his age, it will give in how many years user will be 100 years. But I have assigned an exception if the user enters a negative number to give a value error. But the code runs regardless even if I enter a negative number without raising an exception. Why is that? Thanks! I'm using python 2.7

```
try:
    age = raw_input("Please enter your age: ")
    if age < 0:
        raise ValueError  ('%d is not a positive number' )

except ValueError as err:
    print ("You've entered an incorrect age input %s" %err)

else:
    print("You will be 100 in %d" % (100 - int(age)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input` returns a string, so `age` is a string containing whatever you put - `"-3"` for example. Not an integer.

When comparing an integer to a string, `"-3" < 0`, the integer always "comes first" (is smaller than the string), just as an implementation detail, so your `if` will always be False. Cast to an `int`, the `ValueError` will already catch an invalid cast:

```
age = int(raw_input("Please enter your age: "))
```